# Easiest way to add {{ variable }} from different related model in one template

Tags: django

I got a question. I'm wondering what's the easiest way to add different {{ variable }} from different related model in one template.

I'd like to add some information related to seller rating:

```
def total_seller_ratings(self):
        return self.seller.rating_seller.count() 
        
def avg_seller_ratings(self):
        return self.seller.annotate(avg_ratesugar=Avg('rating_seller__ratesugar')).order_by('-avg_ratesugar')
```

Create a template tag from Middleware? Or is any fastes solution to add another model on my view?

I got a main view for my main page:

```
#Channel MAIN PAGE        
@method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/cooker/login'),name="dispatch")
class ChannelMainPage(generic.DetailView, FormMixin):
    model = Channel
    context_object_name = 'channel'
    template_name = 'channel_detail.html'
    form_class = ChannelChatForm
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChannelMainPage, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.channel = self.object
            form.instance.user = self.request.user
            form.save()
            return super(ChannelMainPage, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(ChannelMainPage, self).form_invalid(form)

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('channel:channel_detail',kwargs={"slug":self.object.slug})
```

models.py

```
class Channel(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_seller")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='channel/')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Make it happen', default=False)

class Rating(models.Model):
    channel = models.OneToOneField(Channel,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="rating_channel")
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='rating_consumer')
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='rating_seller')
    is_rated = models.BooleanField('Already rated', default=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    publishing_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ratesugar = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
     
    def __str__(self):
        return self.channel.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place to add it is on the Model class. This is already available as a variable within the context (see [generic.Detailview.get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data)). It is named "object" and can then be accessed through the templating mechanics.

```py
class Channel(models.Model):
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_consumer", blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="channel_seller")
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,default='user/user-128.png', upload_to='channel/')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('Make it happen', default=False)
    
    def some_method():
        pass
```

template.html

```html
<div>{{ object.some_method() }}</div>
```

Finally, on the discussion (code design) of which model to place the desired methods on...

- If you want to calculate the average over *ALL* ratings it belongs on the `User` model.
- If you want an average over the ratings over a *given channel* then it belongs on the `Channel` model.

Good luck.

PS. Don't forget to prefetch_related to have avoid slow queries!